# Server Sent Event With libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, server-sent-events

I'm creating a multiplayer game with LibGdx.
This game is using a BackEnd using Rest Api and in consequences I'm using http request.

I'm currently looking to use [Server Side Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) in my application but Gdx.net doesn't seem to be compatible with Server Sent Event (from the HTML5 Standardisation)

I Know LibGdx provide some way for accomplish the same goal with TCP connection but I want to avoid that.

Also I'm not against adding third library in my application (if this third library work in Android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've used a third party library.
I've used okHttp with okHttp-sse.

OkHttp is a http Client designed for android so I think it's a good solution for libGdx.

And because I don't want to use 2 http library i don't use libGdx.Net anymore.

One good point about this is that okHttp seems more robust